# Inspect import path string from object

Tags: python, import, inspect

If an object is a module's class or function I need to retrieve the absolute import path as a string. Example:

```
>>> from a.b.c import foo
>>> get_import_path(foo)
'a.b.c.foo'
```

I tried to look into inspect module but there's nothing to do that.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the question you *really* want answered.

Comment: @Ignacio, I think the question is how to implement `get_import_path`.

Comment: @khachik: Except that's not usually useful to know on its own, which means that [there's a real question behind this that isn't being asked](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your are trying to do is inherently impossible.  `foo` simply does not know how you imported it -- it might even have been imported in multiple different ways.  Example on my Linux box:

```
>>> from os.path import normpath
>>> from posixpath import normpath as normpath2
>>> normpath is normpath2
True
```

So `normpath` and `normpath2` are the same function object.  It's impossible to deduce the information in which way they were imported.

That said, it sometimes might help to look at the `__module__` attribute of your function:

```
>>> normpath.__module__
posixpath
>>> normpath2.__module__
posixpath
```

The `__module__` attribute is not always defined, and if it is defined, it does not always contain the information you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `__file__` attribute:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.6/string.pyc'
```